# Can't Build Ionic Project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material, ionic3, ionic4

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

- **What went wrong**:
  Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':`app:preDebugBuild`' property '`compileManifests`' during up-to-date check.

  > The library `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base` is being requested by various other libraries at `[[11.0.1,11.0.1]]`, but resolves to `17.1.0.` Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using `./gradlew :app:dependencies.`
- **Try:**
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
- **What went wrong**:
  Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':`app:preDebugBuild`' property '`compileManifests`' during up-to-date check.

  > The library `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base` is being requested by various other libraries at `[[11.0.1,11.0.1]]`, but resolves to `17.1.0.` Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using `./gradlew :app:dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your cordova-plugin-firebase and add it agian from the [latest major releases](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib).

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib